# php preg_match s and m modifiers not working for multiple lines

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the following input string which consists of multiple lines:

```
BYTE    $66,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$13,$14,$01,$19,$20,$01,$20,$17,$08,$09,$0C,$05,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$66 // comment
BYTE    $66,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$66
```

I use the following preg_match statement to match the data part (so only the hexadecimal values) and not the preceding white space and text, nor the trailing white space and comment sections:

```
preg_match('/(\$.*?) /s', $sFileContents, $aResult);
```

The output is this:

```
output: Array
(
    [0] => $66,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$13,$14,$01,$19,$20,$01,$20,$17,$08,$09,$0C,$05,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$66 
    [1] => $66,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$13,$14,$01,$19,$20,$01,$20,$17,$08,$09,$0C,$05,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$66
)
```

As you may be able to see, the match appears to be correct but the first input line is repeated twice. The 's' modifier should help me get past the end of line, but I cannot seem to get past the first line.

Does anyone have an idea of how to proceed?

Comment: You need no round brackets that create capturing group. The 0th group is the whole match. The first one is the capturing group text. If your data is on one line, remove s flag as it makes the dot match newline symbols. Perhaps you were looking for m flag, but it is useless as you do not have ^ or $ in your pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `s` (DOTALL) flag for this. You can use:

```
preg_match_all('/(\$[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}(?:,\$[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})+)/', $input, $m);
print_r($m[1]);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sL5iD3/3)

Comment: A completely different solution, but with a different expression. This solution repeats the output twice though. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Trust me, it is needed for precise matching. Your accepted solution also matches `$,`

Comment: I'm so sorry, I didn't see that. I've changed the solution. Although I would appreciate a little further explanation on your approach.

Comment: Check out my linked demo as well. It matches a `$` + 2 digit hex code followed by 1 and more occurrences of comma and `$` and 2 digit hex code.

Comment: I hadn't clicked the link before, but I have now. I can see the workings of it and I understand why this does a good job of achieving that. Thanks again, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can match data from all lines easy:

```
preg_match_all('/\$[\dA-Fa-f,\$]+/', $sFileContents, $aResult);
echo "<pre>".print_r($aResult,true);
```

Output:

```
$aResultArray:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => $66,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$13,$14,$01,$19,$20,$01,$20,$17,$08,$09,$0C,$05,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$66
            [1] => $66,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$20,$66
        )

)
```

Comment: thanks! This works. So this matches anything starting with $, consists of a digit, A-F and a-f, a comma and $. I just don't know what the + does.

Comment: "+" indicates there is one or more of the preceding element.